# Update multiple line in terminal with echo

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have an assignment to do for my project and I'm kinda misunderstanding the subject.

***Objectiv***

- Print several lines on the terminal.
- Update in real time the value.

As test, I tried on ten lines emulated from the command `ps` for 30 sec.
`

```
#!/bin/bash
test=$(ps -ao pid,pcpu,time,comm | head -n10)

for time in $(seq 1 30); do
    echo -ne "$test\r"
    sleep 1
    test=$(ps -ao pid,pcpu,time,comm | head -n10)
done
```

- I am aware that my code isn't clean , I'm trying to learn so i visited the man page for console_codes and I get that you  have to use something like `echo -e " text area \033\r"` or something like that to get the correct cursor position in order to update the line and I am fine for one line, but for ten lines I'm completely lost.
- I used a variable to refresh on one `echo` but I get that I'm wrong about the problem.
- If possible I want a solution for my example and the explanation on how I can handle multiple lines because my example print on new lines and doesn't update/erase the old ones.

Note: that example isn't my assignment but it represents the challenge I'm facing right now

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `watch -n1 'ps -ao pid,pcpu,time,comm | head -n10'` ?

Comment: It sure give a solution to my example but the whole point is how to handle it with `echo -e`

Comment: Rephrase your question to make that clear. Btw, I recommend to use `printf` rather than `echo -e` since the latter isn't portable

Comment: @hek2mgl I will do that , If you have time, can you provide me a viable exemple with `printf`

Comment: `printf '%s\r' "$test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, most portable and stable solution would be to clear the screen upon each iteration:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..30} ; do
    clear

    # Print several lines
    printf "foo %d\n" "${i}"
    printf "bar %d\n" "${i}"

    sleep 1
done
```

Alternatively you may use the following sequences:

```
# Save the cursor position
printf "\033[s"
# Print two empty dummy lines
printf "\n\n"

for i in {1..30} ; do
    # Delete the last two lines
    printf "\033[2K"
    # Restore the cursor position
    printf "\033[u"

    # Print two lines
    printf "foo ${i}\n"
    printf "bar ${i}\n"

    sleep 1
done
```

Note that the above ^^^ solution will only work if you know the number of lines to print / clear in beforehand.

Comment: The second one may not work. You need to print two empty lines, then go up two lines, then save the position. If your prompt is on the last line of your terminal, then if you save the cursor position and restore it, you will be on the last line of your terminal. Then printing a newline will shift all lines up. Just `printf "\n\n\033[2K\033[s"`

Comment: True :) ... Changed

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i needed to understand, is how the mechanics of the cursor work :)

Comment: [tldp](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) explains it good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo -e "\e[nA"` to go n lines up (`n` should be an integer). If all lines are of the same length, following will do.

```
lines=10
for i in {0..30}; do
    ps -ao pid,pcpu,time,comm | head -n${lines}  # print `$lines` lines
    sleep 1
    echo -e "\e[$((${lines}+1))A"                # go `$lines + 1` up
done
```